# Excel vba -- Object required error at Sub line

Tags: vba, excel

So I am getting an error at the beginning of my code, an error I didn't use to get last time I opened and edited my VBA code.  Any ideas?  Here is part of it. When I try to step through the code, I get the error: "Object required" and my sub line (first line) is highlighted. Any ideas how I can fix this?

```vb
Sub ManagerCashflow()
   '---------------------------Declare all the variables---------------------------
   '------Define object names------
   'Dim i As Integer
   'Dim c As Integer
   Dim AUM_Cash_Projections_folder_pathname As String
   Dim AUM_Cash_Projections_FOLDER_YEARMONTH_pathname As String
   Dim AUM_Cash_Projections_filename_DATE As String
   Dim AUMCshf_wb As Workbook
   Dim MngrCshF_wb As Workbook
   'Dim CshF_lr As Integer
   'Dim PE_r As Integer
   'Dim lstmanager_r As Integer


   '------Set/call the objects to a destination------
   'Worksheets
   'Manager Cashflow
   Set MngrCshF_wb = ThisWorkbook
   Set MCF_Current_ws = MngrCshF_wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

   'AUM Cash Projections
   Set AUM_Cash_Projections_folder_pathname = "https://iportal.casey.org/Risk Management/CFP Reporting/AUM Cash Projection"
   Set AUM_Cash_Projections_FOLDER_YEARMONTH_pathname = Right(MCF_Current_ws.Cells(2, 1).Value, 7)
   Set AUM_Cash_Projections_filenamedate = MCF_Current_ws.Cells(2, 1).Value
   Set AUMCshf_wb = Workbooks.Open(AUM_Cash_Projections_folder_pathname + "/" + AUM_Cash_Projections_FOLDER_YEARMONTH_pathname + "/" + AUM_Cash_Projections_filenamedate)

   Set CshF_ws = AUMCshf_wb.Sheets("CashFlow + Projections")
        'Master Data with all of the current managers
   Set CurrAssets_ws = AUMCshf_wb.Sheets("Master Data")
   '... a bunch of other code that works....
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need to set a string.  AUM_Cash_Projections_folder_pathname = "https:  Without the set.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it didn't happen before.  You don't need to use set to assign a value to a string.

```
AUM_Cash_Projections_folder_pathname = "https://iportal.casey.org/Risk Management/CFP Reporting/AUM Cash Projection"
AUM_Cash_Projections_FOLDER_YEARMONTH_pathname = Right(MCF_Current_ws.Cells(2, 1).Value, 7)
AUM_Cash_Projections_filenamedate = MCF_Current_ws.Cells(2, 1).Value
```

You also need to declare  MCF_Current_ws and your other worksheets. It won't tell you unless you have "Option Explicit" at the top of your code, but it's good to do.

```
Dim MCF_Current_ws as Excel.Worksheet
```

Comment: One affect of not having `Option Explicit` is you create a new variable called `AUM_Cash_Projections_filenamedate` rather than `AUM_Cash_Projections_filename_DATE`

Comment: You get the error if you try to use set to assign a value that isn't an object. So, instead of `Set x = y`, just do `x = y`.